# Equivalent to "We both" for three (or more) people

Tags: grammatical-number

How do you say something equivalent to "we both" in English when there are three of us?

"We both are Spanish" >> "We three are Spanish"?

Comment: Note that your two-person version *(We **both are** Spanish)* is idiomatically non-standard / stylised / poetic. The natural form is *We **are both** Spanish*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We three are Spanish

and

> We are all Spanish

would work. Another phrase that might work is *the three of us are Spanish*.

The number "three" above can be replaced with any number, actually, but it sounds less idiomatic as the number gets higher. If it's a large group (more than 3 or 4 people) and *all* of you are Spanish, "we are all Spanish" sounds better. If it's a large group and only *some* of you are Spanish, one might say "some of us are Spanish" or "x of us are Spanish", replacing *x* with however many people in the group are Spanish.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/188075/62926), it would be

*"we **all three** are Spanish"*.

Comment: "We all three are Spanish" is not idiomatic. "We three are Spanish" would be correct. See this ngram viewer: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=we+all+three+are%2Cwe+three+are&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cwe%20all%20three%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwe%20all%20three%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWe%20all%20three%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cwe%20three%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bwe%20three%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BWe%20three%20are%3B%2Cc0